# In R sort each element of a list in order and use that order to sample data in a list

Tags: r, list, k-means, knn

Hi I have a few dataframes each representing samples receiving a kind of treatment that I have combined into a list, the idea is I want to test Kmeans clustering method on each of the element/dataframe inside the list, then use the KNN to find closest data point in the data to sub sample.

say I have these 2 dataframes that I bind into a list. Here are sample data https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1B8JQY94Z-BHTZEKlV4dvUDocmiyppBDa?usp=sharing

Each dataframe has the same structure: many rows of samples and 107 columns of variables, but the 1st and 2nd columns are just data labels such as the actual drug treatment.

So I'm trying to perform Kmeans clustering on each element(dataframe) in a list, from the outputs of the kmeans clustering, I took the "centers" that matches each data frame and bind all the centers into another list.

Next, what I want to do is to use the function get.knnx(), so I can use each centers generated by kmeans clustering and with that going back to the original data frame to sample 500 data points that are the closest to the centre, to achieve a good subsampling of the data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purr)

#take data into list
mylist <- list(df1,df2)

#perform Kmeans cluster
#scale datainput and drop the data label column
Kmeans.list <- map(.x = mylist,
                   .f = ~kmeans(scale(.x[,-c(1:2)]),
                        centers =15,
                        nstart=50,
                        iter.max = 100)) %>% 
  purrr::set_names(c("df1", "df2"))


#Isolate the Centers info to another list
Kmeans_centers <- map(Kmeans.list, ~.x$centers)

#trying to use map2
y <- map2(.x = mylist,.y=Kmeans_centers,
          .f=~get.knnx(scale(.x[,-c(1:2)]),.y, 500)) %>% 
    purrr::set_names(c("df1","df2"))
```

The output of get.knnx has 2 components per element in the output list, one is nn.index and the other is the nn.dist. The nn.index represent the actual row index location of the data and thus I want to use this index to go back the original data (df1,df2) to find those data points, and use those data points as the best representative of the data.

I don't quite know how to only use the nn.index part of the list y, so I think first I can take out the nn.index and make them a list

```
#bind all the centers into a list for mapping
y.nnindex <- map(y, ~.x$nn.index)%>% 
  purrr::set_names(c("df1", "df2"))
```

Each index corresponding to df1 or df2 should be 15 X 500, 15 centres chosen from Kmean, and 500 points selected by KNN.

Here is the part I'm stuck, I want to order the nnindex, then use that to subset the original data. I think I can build a list of sampled data then bind them into a dataframe.I get error saying Error in mylist[i][idx, ] : incorrect number of dimensions. I think I'm wrong at how to access the nnindex for each dataframe in the list and how to subset things from the elements of a list. Always stuck with this type of problem. Some pointers and explanations will be much appreciated

```
cl.list <- list()

for (i in 1:2) {
  idx <- sort(y.nnindex[[i]])
  cl.list[[i]] <- as.data.frame(cbind(idx, mylist[i][idx,]))
}
```

Comment: From the error, I guess the bug is the accessor to the list. Try using double square brackets as in: mylist[[i]][idx,]. Basically, double square brackets will collapse the output to the type of data of the element of the list. Single brackets will maintain the output object as type list. The error comes by accessing a list with two indices (hence, incorrect number of dimensions).

Comment: @Ventrilocus thank you, it seems the code worked by that change, I will need to examine the output. I apprecate the way you teach me looking at the [[]], as I always see it as a verb like "access", but if I see it as "collapse" then it makes the intuition much easier for me. Thank you